# Server-side fingerprint: How to read Hello packet from a NodeJs app to generate a JA3?

Tags: ssl, packet, fingerprint, ja3

I'm building an app that need to do some "light" server-side fingerprinting in order to track unique visitors on my website.

For many known reasons, `HTTP` headers are not sufficient to do so (`ip`, `accept-language`, `accept-encoding`, `user-agent`...).

I've recently heard of [`JA3`](https://github.com/salesforce/ja3) and `JA3S` (a method, originated at Salesforce, for profiling SSL/TLS Clients). It seems to fit my need but:

- Surprisingly no NPM library seems to exist for generating JA3/JA3S.
  Have you heard of one?
- Because there is no lib, I could try to write my own.
  It seems "trivial" to generate J3A.

> JA3 gathers the decimal values of the bytes for the following fields
> in the Client Hello packet; SSL Version, Accepted Ciphers, List of
> Extensions, Elliptic Curves, and Elliptic Curve Formats. It then
> concatenates those values together in order, using a "," to delimit
> each field and a "-" to delimit each value in each field.

However, I have no idea how to `console.log()` these data/this `Hello packet` from a NodeJS server app. Do I have to spawn a Python lib or whatever?
(I'm a network/TLS/SSL newbie)

Do you have any clue to help me make progress?

Comment: *"... in order to track unique visitors on my website"* - JA3 is not suitable for this. It will give you the same fingerprint for all instances of Desktop Chrome, Edge ... and then maybe a different one for Firefox. JA3 fingerprints the TLS stack, not the user. And same browser means same TLS stack no matter which user, hardware ... JA3 is more suitable to distinguish normal browsers from bots, but in no way useful to distinguish users.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thanks. I thought it can be used! So there is no other way than http headers to do server-side fingerprinting?

Comment: If you want to actually distinguish between users then no kind of server side fingerprinting has the necessary granularity. These techniques are not about distinguishing users, but about detecting bots etc - i.e. uncommon clients compared to common clients (browsers) where lots of these have the same fingerprint. To actually distinguish users you can try client side fingerprinting (fingerprinting clients hardware) or sending users some value which they send back (most obvious: cookie, less obvious: client-side cached information like etag), use IP address etc.